# Routing in angularJS based on a boolean value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
.config(["$routeProvider", 'partial', 'contentUrl', 'appContext', function ($routeProvider, partial, contentUrl, appContext) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/notifications', {
                templateUrl: partial('popup.html'),
                controller: 'popUpCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    notifications: ['$http', function($http) {
                        return $http.post(
                            appContext('ViewAllNotifications.json'),
                            {"categoryGroupType":"ROLB","isArchived":"N","channelTypeCode":"101","limit":"20","page":"0","customerType":"A"}
                        );
                    }]
                }
            })
        ;
    }])
```

This Code above works perfectly fine. I want to do some condition based routing in this. Can I do something like?

```
.config(["$routeProvider", 'partial', 'contentUrl', 'appContext', function ($routeProvider, partial, contentUrl, appContext) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/notifications',
                if(something){
                templateUrl: partial('popup.html'),
                controller: 'popUpCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    notifications: ['$http', function($http) {
                        return $http.post(
                            appContext('ViewAllNotifications.json'),
                            {"categoryGroupType":"ROLB","isArchived":"N","channelTypeCode":"101","limit":"20","page":"0","customerType":"A"}
                        );
                    }]
                }
            } 
            else{
                templateUrl: partial('popup2.html'),
                controller: 'popUpCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    notifications: ['$http', function($http) {
                        return $http.post(
                            appContext('ViewAllNotifications2.json'),
                            {"categoryGroupType":"ROLB","isArchived":"N","channelTypeCode":"101","limit":"20","page":"0","customerType":"A"}
                        );
                    }]
                }
            })
        ;
    }])
```

Basically I want to load another partial based on a boolean value. Can someone guide me through this? I am pretty new to angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, might work:

```
.config(["$routeProvider", 'partial', 'contentUrl', 'appContext', function ($routeProvider, partial, contentUrl, appContext) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/notifications', {
                templateUrl: function (){
                    if (something) {
                        return partial('popup.html');
                    }
                    else {
                        return partial('popup2.html');
                    }
                },
                controller: 'popUpCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    notifications: ['$http', function($http) {
                        if (something) {
                            return $http.post(
                                appContext('ViewAllNotifications.json'),
                                {"categoryGroupType":"ROLB","isArchived":"N","channelTypeCode":"101","limit":"20","page":"0","customerType":"A"}
                            );
                        }
                        else {
                            return $http.post(
                                appContext('ViewAllNotifications2.json'),
                                {"categoryGroupType":"ROLB","isArchived":"N","channelTypeCode":"101","limit":"20","page":"0","customerType":"A"}
                            );
                        }
                    }]
                }
            } 
        ;
    }])
```